# Varnish Service + PHP URL Paramaters

Tags: php, cookies, parameters, varnish

I am using varnish service to speed up my website, but I cannot make work basic php function. Can you please help me with that ?

```
$purecookie = $_GET['id'];
setcookie( 'purecookies', $purecookie, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60), "/", ".domain.com" );
```

If I turn down varnish service it works correctly, can you please help me? :)

Comment: Please provide more information and your varnish configuration. Also, when it doesn't work, what is happening? Do you get a 404? An error?

Comment: Nothing happening, cookies will not be saved.

Comment: Varnish, by default, ignores requests with cookies.